# I can't start my Ubuntu 20.04 installation (or any other version) on my Lenovo IdeaCentre G5-14AMR 90Q1002YMH

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lenovo

I want to make a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 and when I boot from usb it comes in grub. After I select Ubuntu in the GRUB it gives error messages like this:

```
ACPI BIOS error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.GPP8._DSM], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS
```

What can I do to load the Ubuntu installation?
Does it have something to do with the Lenovo BIOS? Or is this model not supported?